# Cannot install any OS on laptop

Tags: installation

I got Samsung RV520. Installed Win 7 and upgraded to Win 10. I wanted to clone the HDD to move it to SSD. After cloning, I was not able to boot the laptop at all (with the old HDD). So I wanted to reinstall it again, but the installation either stops at black screen, or displays errors about missing files after copying them.

I tried to switch HDD's, switch RAM, play with BIOS settings, reset the MB CMOS, nothing helps. Windows 7 installation stops after copying necessary files, Windows 8 install stops showing the logo, tried to install Ubuntu, run Arch Linux, few other live OS, but always stops at black screen.

Anyone experienced this? Any ideas what to try next? The laptop was working fine for months.

Answer (score 0):

Download and boot from a Live-System, like Ultimate Boot CD and test the Hardware. Especially RAM (Memtest) as this can cause write,read errors.
If you get no errors anywhere, check your Device where you are booting from. For example a faulty or worn out USB-Drive can cause problems as well. Burn a new DVD and verify it or use another USB-Drive.

Comment: I tried to boot several Live systems, it brings me to the main menu, but then again it get stuck